# Socket.io android node.js

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to create a basic chat app between node.js and android, when i run both server and client i can see in the log that they connect and my android app sends a message but the server never receives it, my andoid code is:

```
    private Socket socket;
{
    IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
    opts.forceNew = true;
    opts.reconnection = true;
    try {
        socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.3.7:100");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        Log.e("abc", "index=" + e);
    }
}
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_promociones);
    socket.on("new message", onNewMessage);
    socket.connect();
}
   class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

        ObjWifi.startScan();
        messages =String.valueOf(id)+';'+ Arrays.toString(ret)+';'+String.valueOf(zona);
      socket.emit(messages);
        String str;
        int i1 = r.nextInt(4 - 1) + 1;
        if (zona == 0) {
            str = "img_" + 4;
        } else {
            str = "img_" + zona + "_" + i1;
        }

        fondo.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str, "drawable", getApplicationContext())));

    }

}
```

Also i want to make the incoming messages (allways numbers) to be stored in the variable called zona.

My server side code is:

```
   var express = require('express');  
   var app = express();  
   var server = require('http').Server(app); 
   var io = require('socket.io')(server);
   var messages = [{  
   text: "Hola soy un mensaje",
   author: "Daniel"
   }];
   app.use(express.static('public'));
   io.on('connection', function(socket) { 
   var currentdate = new Date(); 
   var datetime =    currentdate.getDate() + "/"
            + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
            + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
            + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
            + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
            + currentdate.getSeconds();  
    console.log('Alguien se ha conectado con Sockets',datetime);
    socket.emit('messages', messages);
    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
    console.log('Alguien se ha desconectado',datetime);
    });
   socket.on('new-message', function(data) {
   messages.push(data);
   io.sockets.emit('messages', messages);
    });
   });
   server.listen(100, function() {  
   console.log("Servidor corriendo en http://localhost:100");
   });
```

Comment: in your code make indentations, becaouse it is hard to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are listening to certain events that are never triggered.

On server, you are waiting a socket with name "new-message" to trigger your function.

```
socket.on('new-message', function(data) {
   messages.push(data);
   io.sockets.emit('messages', messages);
});
```

This will be triggered after doing an emit with one of those names. Instead, your Android app does the following:

```
  messages =String.valueOf(id)+';'+ Arrays.toString(ret)+';'+String.valueOf(zona);
  socket.emit(messages);
```

With this emit you are taking your messages var content as the name sent to the socket. What you should do is

```
 socket.emit("new-message", messages);
```

This way your server will receive the socket "new-message" and will enter in your function.

For retrieving the data, you may found useful to send it as a JSONObject in both cases, as in Android you are sending a String separating elements by ;, what implies operating that string to obtain each value when received.

In node:

```
socket.on('new-message', function (data) {
        id = data.id;
        RSSI[0] = data.rssi;
        zona = data.zona;
    });
```

In Android:

```
onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
                   @Override
                   public void call(final Object... args) {
                       //args[i] is the data received
                       String data = args[0].toString();
                       try{
                           JSONObject dataJSON = new JSONObject(data);
                           zona = dataJSON.get("zona");
                       }catch(JSONException e){
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                   }
               };
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it solvced my main issue, regarding my other issue, did you know if there is a way to store an upcoming message in a variable? i want to do it in both the server an client side

Comment: Saving the data you are receiving?

Comment: Yes, i would like to do something like zona=socket.on("new message", onNewMessage); on android side, and id=data[0]; RSSI[0]=data[1] and so on, on nodejs side